# Recomemded structure of Git project which uses opensource sub repository

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, github, build

I am planning to build a product which will have some open source components and some commercial components (not open sourced).

The intention is open parts of the products with maximum functionality and get contribution from the community. Where as the commercial features will be available on price.

How should I organise my code and build strategy so that opensource community can build, deploy and run the product on their own whereas the commercial version will use this open source tools as well as the commercial components with it ?

The code I have right now is a Java Spring Boot code base and Node.js code base which has both open and commercial components in them.

I was planning to do the following

```
1. Seperate out the OpenSource components as libraries.
2. Create a build process which will have some default build steps (building the Spring application or Node.js app) + adding the opensource libraries created in Step 1
3. Create a commercial build process (not open sourced) which will have some default build steps + adding the opensource libraries + adding the commercial libraries.
```

Any suggestions if my approach will work, or is there any better alternative available with sub-projects will be appreciated.